# pod trunk - Pushing to repos using different/multiple accounts

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I've registered two accounts with CocoaPods trunk. Is there a way to specify which account to use when pushing, or do I need to re-register with the trunk service each time I push?

Answer (score 2):

Currently the best way to do this is to replace credentials in the ~/.netrc file.  Save, then in the terminal:

```
$ pod trunk me
```

to verify.  I keep another text file open with all the credentials I switch between. Alternatively, only the first set of credentials is used, so adding in all your other credentials after and just swapping them as needed could also work.

Can put your word in [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2822) for them to add a better way of doing this.

Comment: You can also use comment syntax in your `.netrc` file using `#` at the beginning of lines. I find that helpful, rather than juggle multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

Register with another different account with which you want to push the pod. If it is already registered then again register with same email and name and verify it.

```
pod trunk register EmailId 'Name'
```

Then check the detail -

```
pod trunk me
```

Here you will see

- Name:
- Email:
- Since:
- Pods:

  - published_pod1
  - published_pod2 ...
- Sessions:
- Session created detail(Date, Time, IP)